# What does 'if a and b:' mean in python3?

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

**I found this but not understood.**

```py
   c = 0 
   for i in range(len(li)-1):
       if li[i] and li[i+1]:
            li[i] = 0
            li[i+1] = 0
            c+=1
```

Comment: Have you not come across ‘a and b’ in any other circumstances?

Comment: This is the documentation for 'and': https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations. What's the question exactly? Are you familiar with the notion of Boolean 'and' in general?

Comment: Got it.Thanks @Roy2020